# how to update view's height inside a scrollview (NestedScrollView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have a `RecyclerView` with wrap_content in height inside a `NestedScrollView`. I'm trying to update this height in execution time when I receive a response from an API. So when the response is received, I put the items into recyclerview, try to update its height but it don't work. When I force a Pause/Resume states, returning to my app, the recyclerview height is  show correctly. What is making Android to refresh all views?

Comment: you want to update recycle view item(add or modify a row)?

Comment: I want update its height after to receive and add items

Comment: after adding your new item to arraylist of item and call notifyDataSetChanged() method of your recycleview's  adapter it will automatically update height of your view

Comment: the problem isn't add items. The problem is resize (height) the recyclerview inside a scrollview after that the items are loaded.

Comment: @ClarkXP did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @JoshLaird Nope, I used just recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on @mehdi akbarian 's comment, you can try to call notifyDataSetChanged() at the right time (when you response arrives)

```
public void onResponse(.....){
  //do stuff with data

  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

all the measurements triggered by the underlying layout manager will be repeated and a new Layout will be generated.

Comment: the problem isn't add items. The problem is resize (height) the recyclerview inside a scrollview after that the items are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

My similar situation:

```
ScrollView -> normal LinearLayout(MATCH, WRAP, vertical) -> custom SizeCappedLinearLayout(MATCH, WRAP, horizontal)
```

I wanted to set a maximum height for all the dynamic elements inside the ScrollView, based on the height of an outside (header) view. Tricky part was that the height of the header view gets calculated very late after, say, an orientation change. Simply setting LayoutParams wasn't flexible enough.

```
View heightLink = activ.findViewById(R.id.someHeaderView);
SizeCappedLinearLayout scrollLine = new SizeCappedLinearLayout(activ);
scrollLine.setHeightLink(heightLink);
scrollLine.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
scrollLine.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Custom view object:

```
public class SizeCappedLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private View widthLink = null;
    private View heightLink = null;

    public SizeCappedLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void setWidthLink(View v) {
        widthLink = v;
    }

    protected void setHeightLink(View v) {
        heightLink = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if(widthLink != null) {
            heightMeasureSpec = getLinkedSpec(widthLink.getMeasuredHeight(), widthLink.getHeight());
        }
        if(heightLink != null) {
            heightMeasureSpec = getLinkedSpec(heightLink.getMeasuredHeight(), heightLink.getHeight());
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    private int getLinkedSpec(int measureDim, int dim) {
        if(dim > 0) {
            return MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dim, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        } else {
            return MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(measureDim, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        }
    }
}
```